# Read Angular2 POST data in PHP

Tags: php, angular

I want to connect my angular2 app to my PHP backend. Ideally I want to do this:

```
this.http.post('/users/create', {email: email, password: password});
```

The problem is, when I do this my `$_POST` is empty in PHP. What must I do to make this work?

Comment: Well explained here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897266/fetch-and-insert-data-into-mysql-using-angularjs

Comment: That can't be the only solution right? Reading from php://input? I mean with jQuery for example it works with `$_POST` and `json` objects

Comment: @DannySwekker — jQuery doesn't format the request as JSON by default. It uses the application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding. You should also [clear up your apparent misconceptions about what JSON is](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 1):

Angular's http implementation sends data as an `application/json` payload. to read such data from php, you have to use this kind of code :

```php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
// you can even override the `$_POST` superglobal if you want :
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

if you want to send your data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and then be able to read it from php's `$_POST` superglobal without any change to your server code, you need to encode your data as such.

```
const body = new URLSearchParams();
Object.keys(value).forEach(key => {
  body.set(key, value[key]);
}

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
this._http.post(this._contactUrl, body.toString(), {headers}).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

> I mean with jQuery for example it works with $_POST and json objects

it does not work with json object, if you can read data via `$_POST`, it means it has been sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, not `application/json`, parameters are set as a plain js object though...

Comment: Is there any way to have this done by every request? I'm quite confused that it's such a hassle, when I feel that every php application should have this problem right? If they want to work with angularjs

Comment: just create a custom service that will wrap `http` calls. I don't think it's quite a problem because mot people use JSON API to comunicate with the server.

Answer (score 0):

you can use php://input for the post data with angular2 like this and json_decode by this

```
$arr = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),TRUE);
echo "<pre>";print_r($arr);exit;
```

so by this $arr prints the whole post array and used it anywhere you want.