# How send post with form-data in angular2

Tags: angular, post

I try to post datas with angular2 but i have a 400 bad request when i'm trying to post...
With test in postman, everthing is ok, I have a 200 and success

[image: I have a 200 and success...]

But, with angular2

[image: with angular2]

I have a 400 bad request 
What i'm doing wrong ? Thank you !

My code.
Service to call API :

```
userAddReview(paramsObj) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    let params = this.util.transformRequest(paramsObj);
    console.log('sending request');
    return this.authHttp.post(this.wpApiURL + '/users-reviews/reviews?' + params, JSON.stringify({}), { headers: headers })
        .map(
            res => {
                let newReview = res.json();
                this.reviews.push(newReview);
                console.log(this.reviews);
                return newReview;
            }
        );
}
```

Post component :

```
submitReview(form) {
    console.log(this.review, form);
    let params = {
        id: this.review.post,
        user_id: this.wp.getCurrentAuthorId(),
        name: this.wp.getCurrentAuthorId(),
        email: this.wp.getCurrentAuthorId(),
        title:  this.review.rating_title,
        description: this.review.rating_comment,
        rating:     this.review.rating_score,
    };
    console.log("Review", params);
    this.review.author = this.wp.getCurrentAuthorId();
    this.wp.userAddReview(params)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.statusMessage = "Review added successfully!";
                    //clear form
                    form.reset();
                },
                error => {
                    console.log(error._body);
                    this.statusMessage = error._body;
                }
    );
```

Template :

```
<form name="reviewForm" #reviewForm="ngForm" novalidate *ngIf="showPanel()">
    <div *ngIf="!reviewText.valid && (reviewText.dirty || reviewText.touched)" class="alert alert-danger padding">review is required</div>

    <div class="padding">{{statusMessage}}</div>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="review.rating_score" #reviewScore="ngModel" name="reviewScore" placeholder="enter your review score..." required></ion-input>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="review.rating_title" #reviewTitle="ngModel" name="reviewTitle" placeholder="enter your review title..." required></ion-input>
    <ion-textarea
        [(ngModel)]="review.rating_comment"
        #reviewText="ngModel"
        name="reviewText"
        type="text"
        rows="2"
        placeholder="enter your review..."
        required
        >
    </ion-textarea>

    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col *ngIf="!isEditMode"><button ion-button block (click)="submitReview(reviewForm)" [disabled]="!reviewForm.valid">Add</button></ion-col>
            <ion-col *ngIf="isEditMode"><button ion-button block (click)="updateReview(reviewForm)" [disabled]="!reviewForm.valid">Update</button></ion-col>
            <ion-col width-33><button ion-button block (click)="onCancel()">Cancel</button></ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>

</form>

<p *ngIf="!showPanel() && auth.authenticated()" (click)="isEditing = true;">Add Review</p>
<p *ngIf="!auth.authenticated()" (click)="reviewFormNotAuthClicked()">Add Review (login required)</p>
```

Comment: I already answer something like this... Let me find that...

Comment: yup, [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163706/read-angular2-post-data-in-php/41164367#41164367)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chris send the params along with header, Below is the code

```
let url= `${this.wpApiURLl}users-reviews/reviews`;
  let params = new URLSearchParams;
  params.append('id', id);
  params.append('user_id', user_id);
 return this.authHttp.post( url,  { headers:headers,  search:params })
.map(
            res => {
                let newReview = res.json();
                this.reviews.push(newReview);
                console.log(this.reviews);
                return newReview;
            }
        );
```

Comment: Thank you ! But I have the same error.
My request payload with your code is :

{headers: {Content-Type: ["application/json; charset=UTF-8"]},…}
headers
:
{Content-Type: ["application/json; charset=UTF-8"]}
Content-Type
:
["application/json; charset=UTF-8"]
0
:
"application/json; charset=UTF-8"
search
:
"id=5&user_id=1&name=1&email=1&title=sdsd&description=sdqffqs&rating=5"

Comment: Assign the parameters using URLSearchParams  let params = new URLSearchParams;
    params.append('id', id);
        params.append('user_id', user_id);   and send the params along with headers

Comment: Thank you ! I tried, but It doesn't work, cf the next message.

Comment: ok... I just enter params (instead of { search : params} and it's work...

Answer (score 1):

From the request and from the image, it looks like you are sending form data through the url rather than the body of the request.
Change :

```
return this.authHttp.post(this.wpApiURL + '/users-reviews/reviews?' + params, JSON.stringify({}), { headers: headers })
```

To:

```
return this.authHttp.post(this.wpApiURL + '/users-reviews/reviews', params, { headers: headers })
```

Remember to set params as URLSearchParams object.
`let params = new URLSearchParams()`

Comment: Thank you Suraj, despite of remove the stringify, the problem still here.

Comment: Set params as URLSearchParams and send as body

Comment: I tried, I post the code on the previous message, but my resquest payload is empty.

Comment: ok... I just enter params (instead of { search : params} and it's work...

Answer (score 1):

@Venkateswaran, nothing really better :

```
    let params = new URLSearchParams;
    params.append('id', '5');
    params.append('user_id', '1');
    console.log('sending request');
    return this.authHttp.post(url, { search:params })
        .map(
            res => {
                let newReview = res.json();
                this.reviews.push(newReview);
                console.log(this.reviews);
                return newReview;
            }
        )
        .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.statusMessage = "Review added successfully!";
                    //clear form
                    form.reset();
                },
                error => {
                    console.log(error._body);
                    this.statusMessage = error._body;
                }
    );
}
```

And the request paylod is empty :

```
{
  "search": {
    "rawParams": "",
    "queryEncoder": {},
    "paramsMap": {}
  }
}
```